MqttClientOptionsBuilder call option failed in Dot net MAUI app, while running on android emulator, working fine on windows emulator
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Private.Xml.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/Demo.mobile/files/.override/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/Demo.mobile/files/.override/System.Private.Xml.dll [External]
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.dll
[monodroid-assembly] open_from_bundles: failed to load assembly System.Security.Cryptography.dll
Loaded assembly: /data/data/Demo.mobile/files/.override/System.dll [External]
Loaded assembly: /data/data/Demo.mobile/files/.override/System.Security.Cryptography.dll [External]
15:50:39:192    [monodroid-assembly] Shared library 'liblog' not loaded, p/invoke '__android_log_print' may fail
15:50:39:395    [DOTNET] Connecting to MQTT Broker
15:51:16:727    [DOTNET] Error: Could not find file '/C:\Users\Desktop\Api_Integration\Demo.Mobile\Resources\certf\group-ca.pem

Well, it says very clear what file cannot be accessed. (the cert).

Android does not have a C:\ drive

This is I am also trying to understand, how to use relative path in such case? @jason

@Jason How do we give path for app that would more like to be deployed in windows & android platform?

is this a file that will be deployed with the app bundle, or something the user supplies?

@Jason this file is supplied by user.

Then why don’t you let the user select the file instead of hardcoding the path?

It looks like you only needed 1 line of that log output (2 at most). The log would have been more legible if marked up as a code block. When others have tried to edit the question to format it as described, they would also have needed to add some text to the question body. Some details like the emulators that you tried could have been placed in the question body rather than title.

we have to keep that file in particular folder and then access from that folder in MAUI application like Resource -> Cert-> cert.pem, group.pem, priv-key.pem. now question is how we can access that file from folder? Android emulator not supporting but for windows emulator working fine.

@Jason Can you pls explain how you let user select such file? Usually this is certificate related file and should not be exposed to app user.

you just told me that "this file is supplied by user"

It is supplied by developer

@Jason this file not supposed supplied by user, in coding itself we have to get from project folder MAUI application like Resource -> Cert-> cert.pem, group.pem, priv-key.pem.

you need to add the cert to your project folder so it is deployed with your app, and then load it from there
